# Install 32 bit c++ on 64 bit linux because TimeStamp.h is not found

Tags: c++, amazon-ec2

I'm on the amazon ec2 64 bit linux machine having c++ code which when I compile:

```
g++ -O3 -o capp capp.c MinitGlobal.h Item.c ItemsetQueue.c Transaction.c Error.h Dataset.c SubDataset.c RankItems.c MinitAlgo.c
```

I get:

```
capp.c:9:23: fatal error: TimeStamp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This is probably gcc or g++ is improperly installed, though I installed lots of packages (using `sudo yum install ...`). But maybe missed something.

Comment: what function are you looking for?

Comment: No, it's *not* "probably gcc or g++ is improperly installed". There's no `TimeStamp.h` header that's supposed to be part of a GCC installation.

Comment: And what does 32-bit vs. 64-bit have to do with it?

Comment: I know that if I install gcc or g++ with its libs properly this error will disappear. Because this file is from some old c library.

Comment: Looks like you are just missing a library. What distro are you using ?

Comment: It's `Linux version 3.4.73-64.112.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-31003) (gcc version 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2) (GCC) )`. Amazon 64 bit instance.